# how to utilize a static class to wrap configuration values?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I am attempting to retrieve config values with a static class:

```
public static class Configurator
{
    public static string HashesConnectionString { get; } = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HashesConnectionString");
    public static string SftpUser { get; } = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SftpUser");}
```

When attempting to retrieve these from a separate class, I am getting a very embarrassing error:

```
System.TypeInitializationException
  HResult=0x80131534
  Message=The type initializer for 'MyHandler.Configuration.Configurator' threw an exception.
  Source=MyHandler
  StackTrace:
   at MyHandler.Configuration.Configurator.get_HashesConnectionString() in C:\Users\John.S\source\repos\MyHandler\MyHandler\Configuration\Configurator.cs:line 11
   at MyHandler.OnMumboCaseBlobTriggered.RunAsync(CloudBlockBlob blob, String name, TraceWriter log) in C:\Users\John.S\source\repos\MyHandler\MyHandler\Functions\OnMumboCaseBlobTriggered.cs:line 31
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidMethodInvoker`2.InvokeAsync(TReflected instance, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.<InvokeAsync>d__9.MoveNext()

Inner Exception 1:
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: String
```

Initially I thought something funny was happening with `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()` but this did not turn out to be the case, when I tested this hypothesis by *hardcoding* the config values like so:

```
public static class Configurator
{
   public static string HashesConnectionString {get;} = "my hardcoded value"
}
```

But the exception persists!

**What is wrong with my static class? Am I improperly using this class?**

This exception occurs in this example:

```
public static void RunAsync([BlobTrigger("awesomeBlobber", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")] CloudBlockBlob blob, string name, TraceWriter log)
{
               var connString = Configuration.Configurator.HashesConnectionString;
```

}

Comment: The error points to `HashesConnectionString` which is not included in the code snippets above. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). A [mcve] should help clarify the actual problem

Comment: I believe you have some logic inside get_HashesConnectionString getter that's failed. Also I assume you're trying to do some work around connection string but you have specified a wrong environment variable name (from where it should be read) and got 'null' instead of it's value.

Comment: @IgorGnedysh there is no logic, sir. it's a simple `get`. hardcoding the value `public static string HashesConnectionString {get;} = "my hardcoded value"` yielded the same exception

Comment: @MoreOrLessYou great question. no there are not. i've attempted to add a public constructor and got the same exception

Comment: Are you sure you do not have some kind of namespace clashing.  Try to modify the name space. Also shouldnt you have `=>` instead of `=` ?

Comment: @AlexGordon Just for troubleshooting, what happens when you do `var connString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HashesConnectionString");` directly in the function?

Comment: Yea that link sugests there is some kind of constructor exception. The nature of "singletons" is a bit difficult to debug. I would suggest commenting out as much as possible and start from simple. First just empty class, then add a property one by bye until the error comes up. As others suggested, it could be one of those classes you are using.. the hashesconfig thing?

Comment: @ppumkin i've also attempted to change the class to regular `public class` but leaving the `public static string`

Comment: maybe its the public static string with those initialisers. try to set the value by using the default static constructor instead. put a break point in the `{` on the constructor and step through. If you cant break at the default static constructor there is an issue outside of this class. As I had sometimes, namespace clashing or some other stupid reason, or hidden exceptions withing whatever you are trying to get. It could be 32bit/64bit dll hell too - since you are using somekind of Azure kit.

Comment: I don't think you are improperly using the static class but using static classes "singletons" is very rare case for now. You should consider using normal classes and Dependency Injection (ideally with an Interface on them) You can define the lifetime of your class as a singleton, without actually making it a singleton. They cause more problems than solve I have found and use cases are very rare. Best use case for them is Factory Pattern - but again, Dependency Injection is  far better,easier and scalable.

Comment: Well, what you are seeing is weird.  I took your "hardcoded value" example, dropped it in some code and it "just worked".  I put a breakpoint on the access to the property, and on the property itself and everything ran as excepted.  The example you show the property being accessed from is named `RunAsync`, but the method isn't marked `async`.  Is it?  Async methods build up little state machines within the function.  That could be the issue.  Does the issue repro if you just access the property from your `Main` function for something else that's "plain vanilla"?